# how to parse unsigned char array to numerical data

Tags: c++, arrays, string, unsigned-char

The setup of my question is as follows:

- I have a source sending a UDP Packet to my receiving computer
- Receiving computer takes the UDP packet and receives it into `unsigned char *message`.

I can print the packet out byte-wise using

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(message); i++) {
    printf("0x%02 \n", message[i];
}
```

And this is where I am!  Now I'd like to start parsing these bytes I recieved into the network as shorts, ints, longs, and strings.

I've written a series of functions like:

```
short unsignedShortToInt(char[] c) {
    short i = 0;
    i |= c[1] & 0xff;
    i <<= 8;
    i |= c[0] & 0xff;
   return i;
}
```

to parse the bytes and shift them into ints, longs, and shorts.  I can use `sprintf()` to create strings from byte arrays.

My question is -- what's the best way to get the substrings from my massive UDP packet?  The packet is over 100 character in lengths, so I'd like an easy way to pass in `message[0:6]` or `message[20:22]` to these variation utility functions.

Possible options:

- I can use `strcpy()` to create a temporary array for each function call, but that seems a bit messy.
- I can turn the entire packet into a string and use `std::string::substr`.  This seems nice, but I'm concerned that converting the unsigned chars into signed chars (part of the string conversion process) might cause some errors (maybe this concern is unwarranted?).
- Maybe another way?

So I ask you, stackoverflow, to recommend a clean, concise way to do this task!

thanks!

Comment: I see that in your "series of functions" you've brought in variable `c` as a function input, but are using variable `b` in the body of the function; is this just a typo for this question?

Comment: You need to know the sending (applicative) protocol. What is the layout of the messages ? Once you know that, you can declare the corresponding `struct`, and cast accordingly.

Comment: And `return i;` had better flag your compiler with an error. The function `unsignedShortToInt` returns `void` (which is likely another typo).

Comment: Do you know the structure of the message or you just need a function to take the array and parse any index-to-index part?

Comment: abiessu, WhozCraig: Whoops, those are typos! Fixed.

quantdev: I know the format (which bytes correspond to what), but I'm trying to figure out how to take message[0:4] and store that as a long in a struct.

Jay: See above.  Though, I suppose, I could just input the indexes into each of the parsing functions I wrote.

Comment: I think you could go without problems into using `std::string`. If you want to preserve unsigned chars, you can use `std::basic_string<unsigned char>` instead, but I don't think it will affect you

Comment: The method you are using to convert bytes to integers is platform dependent. The functions that are typically used to make sure byte order is correct for the platform are `htons()` etc... http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html

Comment: so after constructing a short with my function, should I use something like `ntohs()` to make sure the byte ordering is correct? or am I suppose to use them differently?

Comment: @Galik: No, this sort of code *is* the platform-independent way.  `htons` is a platform-dependent function for correcting data after some other code did something unportable like a pointer cast.

Comment: Your `unsignedShortToInt()` is effectively a re-implementation of `ntohs()` so why re-invent the wheel? Use the standard library function that's been well tested.

Comment: How would I pass multiple bytes to ntohs()?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [proper](http://msgpack.org/) [serialization](http://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/) [?](http://google.github.io/flatbuffers/)

i.e. [MsgPack](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c)

You'll need a scheme how to differentiate messages. You could for example make them [self-describing](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#self-description), something like:

```
struct my_message {
  string protocol;
  string data;
};
```

and dispatch decoding based on the protocol.

You'll most probably be better off using a tested serialization library than finding out that your system is vulnerable to buffer overflow attacks and malfunction.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two problems to solve here. First you need to make sure the integer data are properly aligned in memory after extracting them from the character buffer. next you need to ensure the correct byte order of the integer data after their extraction.

The alignment problem can be solved with a `union` containing the integral data type super-imposed upon a character array of the correct size. The network byte order problem can be solved using the standard `ntohs()` and `ntohl()` functions. This will only work if the sending software also used the standard byte-order produced by the inverse of these functions.

See: http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html

Here are a couple of UNTESTED functions you may find useful. I think they should just about do what you are after.

```
#include <netinet/in.h>

/**
 * General routing to extract aligned integral types
 * from the UDP packet.
 *
 * @param data Pointer into the UDP packet data
 * @param type Integral type to extract
 *
 * @return data pointer advanced to next position after extracted integral.
 */
template<typename Type>
unsigned char const* extract(unsigned char const* data, Type& type)
{
    // This union will ensure the integral data type is correctly aligned
    union tx_t
    {
        unsigned char cdata[sizeof(Type)];
        Type tdata;
    } tx;

    for(size_t i(0); i < sizeof(Type); ++i)
        tx.cdata[i] = data[i];

    type = tx.tdata;

    return data + sizeof(Type);
}

/**
 * If strings are null terminated in the buffer then this could be used to extract them.
 *
 * @param data Pointer into the UDP packet data
 * @param s std::string type to extract
 *
 * @return data pointer advanced to next position after extracted std::string.
 */
unsigned char const* extract(unsigned char const* data, std::string& s)
{
    s.assign((char const*)data, std::strlen((char const*)data));
    return data + s.size();
}

/**
 *  Function to parse entire UDP packet
 *
 * @param data The entire UDP packet data
 */
void read_data(unsigned char const* const data)
{
    uint16_t i1;
    std::string s1;
    uint32_t i2;
    std::string s2;

    unsigned char const* p = data;

    p = extract(p, i1); // p contains next position to read
    i1 = ntohs(i1);

    p = extract(p, s1);

    p = extract(p, i2);
    i2 = ntohl(i2);

    p = extract(p, s2);
}
```

Hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

I have edited the example to include strings. It very much depends on how the strings are stored in the stream. This example assumes the strings are null-terminated c-strings.

**EDIT2:**

Whoopse, changed code to accept **unsigned** chars as per question.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is only 100 characters in length just create a `char buffer[100]` and a `queue` of them so you don't miss processing any of the messages.

Next you could just index that buffer as you described and if you know the struct of the message then you know the index points.

next you can `union` the types i.e

```
union myType{
    char buf[4];
    int x;
 }
```

giving you the value as an int from a char if thats what you need

Comment: That only works if the sending machine has the same endianness as the receiving, which is not guaranteed. The hton* and ntoh* functions should be used on both ends.

Comment: True, but if you know the packet payload structure that could be a simple check on receiving.